# How to detect if a printer support ESC/P 2 in VB6?

Tags: printing, vb6, escp2

Not all printer support **ESC/P 2**, my question is it any method to detect is a printer support **ESC/P 2** before we send the codes to the printer?

Programming language is **VB6**.

Comment: I briefly reviewed the [reference manual](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) and did a little searching on the web.  I didn't see a way to detect printer support.